# Embedded VLC player in tkinter not able to play online videos

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, https, vlc

Basically the title, this is my code, it works on local files but an error pops out when I type in a URL:

```
import vlc
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class Screen(tk.Frame):

    '''
    Screen widget: Embedded video player from local or youtube
    '''

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg='black')
        self.parent = parent
        # Creating VLC player
        self.instance = vlc.Instance()
        self.player = self.instance.media_player_new()

    def GetHandle(self):
        # Getting frame ID
        return self.winfo_id()

    def play(self, _source):
        # Function to start player from given source
        Media = self.instance.media_new(_source)
        Media.get_mrl()
        self.player.set_media(Media)

        self.player.set_hwnd(self.winfo_id())
        self.player.play()


root = tk.Tk()
player = Screen(root)
player.place(x=0, y=0, width=500, height=300)
player.play('https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ')
root.mainloop()
```

**My Errormessage**: [0000020be7103c00] http stream error: local stream 1 error: Cancellation (0x8)

Answer (score 0):

you should be sure the link has an extension like "**.mp4**" or "**.flv**" or ...

like that :

```
import vlc
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class Screen(tk.Frame):

    '''
    Screen widget: Embedded video player from local or youtube
    '''

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg='black')
        self.parent = parent
        # Creating VLC player
        self.instance = vlc.Instance()
        self.player = self.instance.media_player_new()

    def GetHandle(self):
        # Getting frame ID
        return self.winfo_id()

    def play(self, _source):
        # Function to start player from given source
        Media = self.instance.media_new(_source)
        Media.get_mrl()
        self.player.set_media(Media)

        self.player.set_hwnd(self.winfo_id())
        self.player.play()

root = tk.Tk()
player = Screen(root)
player.place(x=0, y=0, width=500, height=300)
player.play('https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4')
root.mainloop()
```